# combine cp / chmod to modify perms during cp

Tags: bash, awk, sed, chmod, cp

I was looking for a way to cp a file and mod its perms to 400 at the same time... after some testing in the public_html folder...

```
public_html >> ls -lah
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    0 Feb 27 14:21 a.txt
public_html >> cp a.txt{,.bak}
-rw-r--r--  1 user user    0 Feb 27 14:21 a.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb 27 14:23 a.txt.bak
```

perms are still the same (644) and although the file is owned by root, it is still readable via public_html

```
public_html >> cp a.txt{,.bak} && chmod 400 a.txt.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  653 Feb 27 14:26 a.txt
-r--------  1 root root  653 Feb 27 14:30 a.txt.bak
```

this works but looking for something for a set newbs to use

awk/sed command possibly?

dont think I'm missing a cp flag that could modify the perms, wasn't seeing anything and don't think there are but wanted to pick the collective brain

thanks...

Comment: Do you think than `sed/awk` could be better for newbs to use? You could try set the `umask 077` before the `cp`.

Answer (score 6):

`install(1)` can both copy files and create directories, and set their permissions at the same time.

```
install -m 0400 foo bar/
```

Comment: nice!

`
public_html >> install -m 0400 a.txt{,.bak}
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  653 Feb 27 14:26 a.txt
-r--------  1 root   root   653 Feb 27 15:56 a.txt.bak
`

thanks :D